# count new lines in textarea to resize container in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have a textarea submitted to a php file.

Im using this to make it look exactly as the user entered the text:

```
 $ad_text=nl2br(wordwrap($_POST['annonsera_text'], 47, "\n", true));
```

If I want to resize a container I must be able to read how many lines are in the variable '$ad_text'.

Is there a way to do this...

I am still learning so thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expression:

```
preg_match_all("/(\n)/", $text, $matches);
$count = count($matches[0]) + 1; // +1 for the last tine
```

**EDIT:** Since you use nl2br so '`\n`' is replaced by `<br>`. So you need this code.

```
preg_match_all("/(<br>)/", $text, $matches);
$count = count($matches[0]) + 1; // +1 for the last tine
```

However, `<br>` will not be display as newline in textarea (if I remember correctly) so you may need to remove `nl2br`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: nl2br() doesn't replace "\n"; it adds "<br />" right before it. If the line ending is "\r\n", the "<br />" is added before the "\r"; if there is only "\r" (but no "\n"), "<br />" is still added before it.

Comment: @GZipp: Thanks for clearify. I have not used it for quite sometime.

Answer (score 4):

You want the [substr_count function](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
$lines = explode("\n", $text);
$count = count($lines);
$html = implode($lines, "<br>");
```

Comment: I don't think you need to do implode.

Comment: The parameters for explode() are backwards. Try explode("\n", $text);