# Count lines in a posted string

Tags: php, count, lines

I've tried this: [count new lines in textarea to resize container in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743745/count-new-lines-in-textarea-to-resize-container-in-php)

But it doesn't seems to be working:

```
$content = nl2br($_POST['text']);
preg_match_all("/(<br>)/", $content, $matches);

echo count($matches[0]) + 1;
```

It'll always output `1`.

Is there any other solutions to count lines in a string?

Comment: Did you check if nl2br is outputting `<br />` instead?

Comment: In the firebug it shows `<br>` .

Comment: Output $content, it might be converting the linebreaks to <br/> Firebug doesn't show the actual markup, so don't trust it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found this in one of my old apps... Not sure where I got it from.

```
$lines_arr = preg_split('/\n|\r/',$str);
$num_newlines = count($lines_arr); 
echo $num_newlines;
```

*Edit - Actually, this probably won't work if your textarea is spitting out html.. check for `<br> and <br/>`

Comment: Thank you! It's working great. If someone will be looking for solution: I've just changed your reg. exp into: `preg_split('/(<br \/>)/', $str);`.

Comment: No problem. You might want to hit the green checkbox next to this answer so people know it's been answered.

Comment: edited the answer to take into account of \r\n and \n\r otherwise, this is fantastic answer. I also needed this.

Comment: Hey, is there a reason for having `\r` in the regex?

Comment: I am not sure if this is the best option when file is big, e.g. 250 MB

Answer (score 11):

You can try this:

```
$count = substr_count($_POST['text'], "\n") + 1;
```

or:

```
$count = count(explode("\n", $_POST['text']));
```

Answer (score 6):

```
count( explode(PHP_EOL, $str) );
```